# No sound from Windows 7 on MacBook Pro 2.8GHz

Tags: boot, macbook-pro, multi-boot

I have installed Windows 7 64-bit on a MacBook Pro 2.8GHz. The only sound that comes is when Windows 7 is booting up - i.e. Windows can detect the drivers. However once Windows 7 is up and running, there is no sound from the computer at all!

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: What version Macbook Pro do you have? It would under Apple Logo (Top Left corner) => About => and here it will say a version like "Macbook Pro 5,2"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you install the bootcamp drivers off of the OSX Snow Leopard disc... are you seeing a red beam coming out of the headphone jack? It's possible it is switching to optical out.